# Autoit user Gui idle close Timeout

Tags: timeout, autoit, idle-timer

I created a GUI Program with Autoit.

I want to add a idle Timeout to my program to be automatically closed After the timeout has elapsed (Similar to InputBox  & MsgBox). But it has no option for it...

Is ther any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [AdlibRegister](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AdlibRegister.htm)

```
GuiCreate() 

AdlibRegister("MyTimeoutFunc", 10000); runs every 10s

While True
  Sleep(100)
Wend

Func MyTimeoutFunc()
  Exit
EndFunc
```

Or using [TimerInit](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/TimerInit.htm) and [TimerDiff](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/TimerDiff.htm)

```
GuiCreate() 

$sTimer = TimerInit() 

While TimerDiff($sTimer) < 10000 ;Runs for 10s
  Sleep(100)
Wend

Exit
```